# How to rewrite URL from query parameters to path segments

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I need to create url like this

```
www.abc.com/index/en
```

My current url like this

```
www.abc.com/?i=page.index&lang=en
```

Please help me to rewrite url..

Comment: You will find hundreds of existing answers here that demonstrate _exactly_ what you ask.

Comment: Can you help me for this case?

Comment: Why do yo think it helps to write one more answer if there already are answers that demonstrate what you ask? There is a reason why I mentioned that to you. It should motivate you to look at those answers.

Comment: Thanks for ur attention..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rewrite your URL you have follow these steps below :-

- Create a new file into root directory (in-short create a file into `htdocs` folder of your website) with name of `.htaccess`,
- Copy the code and paste it into the file which will you create earlier.

**Code :-**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /i/(.*)/lang/(.*)/ ?i=$1&lang=$2
RewriteRule /i/(.*)/lang/(.*) ?i=$1&lang=$2
```

This code change this URL

```
www.abc.com/?i=page.index&lang=en
```

Into this URL

```
www.abc.com/i/page.index/lang/en/
```

Hope this will helpful for you, thank you .